# php - decoding function (bytes and integers)

Tags: php, binary, byte, bit

I'm being asked to write a decoding function that accepts two bytes on input, both in the range [0x00..0x7F] and recombine them to return the corresponding integer between [-8192..+8191].

Exemplary table that comes with the problem:

```
Hi byte | Lo byte | Value
40      | 00      | 0
00      | 00      | -8192
7F      | 7F      | 8191
50      | 00      | 2048
0A      | 05      | -6907
55      | 00      | 2688
```

It's an assignment and I hate it because PHP isn't optimized to interact with operating systems so much as it is to web browsers. It's all about bits and bytes and binary data, stuff that you seldom need to use in PHP; seems like an assignment for C/C++ or Java. Anyway, I have to write it in PHP.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Start by taking a look at PHP's [bitwise operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

Comment: Unless you know how to combine the two input bytes into the output value, the language won't matter much.

Comment: Yea I'm actually taking a look at those bitwise operators. I've just never really been exposed to anything having to do with bits and bytes and all that jazz. I've studied PHP extensively. I have a book here: "PHP and MySQL Web Development; Developers Library" by Luke Welling and Laura Thomson. It's supposed to be the 'Gold Standard' in PHP programming, and they devote half a page to bitwise operators. They say: "You probably will not find a lot of use for the bitwise operators in PHP, but a summary is shown in Table 1.5..." The book is 968 pages.